# URIMatcher doesn't match

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

This was working! I'm not sure what changed. I do use git and I have looked over my commits and the code for hours now.

As the title indicates my uri matcher stopped matching.

Below I have pasted the relevant parts of my content provider.

```
public class Provider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String TAG = "Provider";
    private static final String SCHEME = ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT;
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.snot.bodyweightworkout.database.provider";
    private static final String BASE_URI = SCHEME + AUTHORITY;

    public static final Uri URI_EXERCISES = Uri.parse(BASE_URI + "/exercise");
    public static final Uri URI_PROGRAMS = Uri.parse(BASE_URI + "/program");
    public static final Uri URI_PROGRAM_EXERCISES = Uri.parse(BASE_URI + "/program/#/exercise");

    private static final int EXERCISE = 1;
    private static final int EXERCISES = 2;
    private static final int PROGRAM = 3;
    private static final int PROGRAMS = 4;
    private static final int PROGRAM_EXERCISES = 5;

    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static
    {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/exercise", EXERCISES);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/exercise/#", EXERCISE);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/program", PROGRAMS);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/program/#", PROGRAM);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/program/#/exercise", PROGRAM_EXERCISES);
    }
```

...

And then the part where the actual matching should take place.

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Log.v(TAG, "URI: " + uri);
    Cursor result = null;
    int match = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch(match)
    {
        case PROGRAMS:
            result = DatabaseHandler
                .getInstance(getContext())
                .getReadableDatabase()
                .query(Program.TABLE_NAME, Program.FIELDS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            result.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), URI_PROGRAMS);
            break;
        case PROGRAM:
            final long pid = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            result = DatabaseHandler
                .getInstance(getContext())
                .getReadableDatabase()
                .query(Program.TABLE_NAME, Program.FIELDS,
                        Program.COL_ID + " IS ?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(pid) }, null, null, null, null);
            result.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), URI_PROGRAMS);
            break;
       ...
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unmatched(" + match + ") URI: " + uri.toString());
```

I'm trying to query using a cursor loader like this:

```
     getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
         @Override
         public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
             return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Provider.URI_PROGRAMS, Program.FIELDS, null, null, null);
         }
```

Everytime default is hit. Not match is made the I end up with a FC and the following line in my log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1979): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unmatched(-1) URI: content://com.snot.bodyweightworkout.database.provider/program
```

I've been starring at this for hours and I really need some fresh eyes to take a peak at it. So if some kind soul could take a look at it I will appreciate it very much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to try without the starting `/`, so `program` instead of `/program` in the `addUri()` method.

Comment: You are the man!!! Earlier today my samsung galaxy s3 broke and I'm testing this one an old  HTC Desire with cm7.2. Thanks!

Comment: @Luksprog please upgrade your comment to an answer so I can close using that if you want the credits.

Comment: Leading `/` was added in Jelly Bean 4.3 so just don't use it, it only limits compatibility and increases laziness in some cases where parsing is involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the starting `/`, so define your `addUri()` method calls like this:

```
static {
   sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "exercise", EXERCISES);
   sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "exercise/#", EXERCISE);
   sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "program", PROGRAMS);
   sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "program/#", PROGRAM);
   sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "program/#/exercise", PROGRAM_EXERCISES);
}
```